# Add multiple Fields For the CamlQuery in Sharepoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml-query, jsom, filter, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am trying to filter two fields or more that is clean of null values.

It works for the first field but it is not working for the second field:

```
<View><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='CustomField'/></IsNotNull><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='LaborCategory'/></IsNotNull></Where></Query></View>
```

Comment: What is the data type of `LaborCategory` and `CustomField` columns?

Answer (score 0):

You need nested query.
For each column you need to add AND/OR in query.
See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204309/4069473

Comment: I tried this solution but got undefined as well

Answer (score 0):

Try using below CAML query:

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <AND>
        <IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='CustomField'/></IsNotNull>
        <IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='LaborCategory'/></IsNotNull>
      </AND>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

**Official documentations**:

1. [IsNotNull element (Query)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/IsNotNull-element-query)
2. [CAML Query schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/Query-schema)

Comment: it does not work actually because am trying to iterate the list to get two results and i think i cant do that, so that i did function for each one

Comment: here is what am trying to do after mapping the caml query:  while (listItemEnumerator1.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem1 = listItemEnumerator1.get_current();
                $("#labcategory").append('<option>' + oListItem1.get_item('LaborCategory') + '</option>')
                $("#company").append('<option>' + oListItem1.get_item('CustomField') + '</option>')

            }

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is already answered. I would still recommend you to use U2U which will help you create and understand complex CAML queries in the future.